# React Native TypeError:Network Request Failed on Android 9(Pie) Device

Tags: android, react-native

My application with react-native Android 9 (Pie) emulator works well.
Then I create Apk and this Apk doesn't work on my Android (9 Pie) device. Android 8, Android 7, Android 6 works. But it doesn't work on my Android 9 device.
Error when I install apk on Android 9: TypeError: Network Request Failed

React-native: 0.59.9

Comment: How do you creates the apk?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android